# Date in SQL string from DateTimePicker

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to insert a date from a DateTimePicker in a Windows Form in VB.Net into an SQL string in such a way as it recognises it as a datetime (the field itself is set as datetime in SQL Server).

I have tried a few methods (`Convert` at SQL level, `Format` at VB.Net level) and am now using a variable stored as `DateTime`, however I still cannot get it to work. A snippet of my code is below:

```
Using sqlConn = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.sqlString)
        sqlConn.Open()
        Dim dte As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Me.dateMain.Text)
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        cmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand
        cmd.CommandText = "Update Table1 " &
        "SET Person='" & Me.person.Text & "'," &
        "Date='" & dte & "' " &
        "WHERE (Code = '" & PCode & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd = Nothing
End Using
```

EDIT:
The following error (or slight variation of) is what I have got with almost every attempt I have tried. This error was received after the Parameterization answer submitted below

> **An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll**
>
> **Additional information: The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.**

So it seems that even still, it is not recognising it as a datetime in SQL. I imagine I will need to try again with `Convert` in the SQL string, but my knowledge of the function is limited. Anyone know how I can use it to get this to work (if that is the solution)?

Comment: As far as I remember, `DateTimePicker` control in Windows Form has a property `Value` which returns the `DateTime` selected in control. Use this property so you don't need to convert `String` into `DateTime`

Comment: It does, but this was not playing well when used in the SQL statement. It seemingly converted the Value to a string within the SQL string, giving me something on the lines of `Date=#3/4/12#` which didnt work in a connection string, hence my switch to using `.Text` which gives the date in a more recognizable text format for SQL

Comment: I think all you need is a space before the "WHERE". `" WHERE (Code = '" & PCode & "')"`

Comment: Its not that (thats correct in the original, will amend OP)

Comment: Amended. Also, that would not cause the error as described above

Comment: @bmgh1985, if you are using parameters, your Data Types in your table are all good, the values you are putting in parameters match the value in your DB, then no way this error can occur. If you send us complete code maybe we can find exact point where problem is, and if code is too long you can create a simple example first to check the error.

Comment: @sallushan Have tested using my sample example above as well (its just the first 2 columns of my full data set and the only one with a datetime is the one shown) and it still does not work, so there is a way the error can occur. Just need to figure out why.

Comment: Switched to `.Value` in the Parameter this time and it worked OK.

Comment: @sallushan the `.Value` worked better in the Parameter than it did in the connection string. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a job for parameterization!

```
Using sqlConn = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.sqlString)
    sqlConn.Open()
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    cmd = sqlConn.CreateCommand
    cmd.CommandText = "Update Table1 " &
        "SET Person = @person, " &
        "Date = @dte " &
        "WHERE (Code = @code)"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@person", Me.person.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dte", Me.dateMain.Value)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", PCode)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd = Nothing
End Using
```

And while you're at it, I don't want to change too much because I've never written a line of VB in my life (so this also may or may not be right, let me know if it doesn't compile or something, but this is the gist), but `SqlCommand` does implement `IDisposable`, so you should probably wrap that in a `Using` as well.

Parameterizing your queries will eliminate bugs like you've come across, promote code reuse, and arguably most importantly, stop SQL Injection attacks. Please always use parameters, for all our sakes.

Comment: Was hoping that wasn't the solution, but knew deep down it probably was. It's only a simple form for one person at work to use, so code injection wasn't really something I was considering combating, but it probably is the best way to get round it. Will test and let you know, thanks.

Comment: @bmgh1985 As a general rule, every little bit of code you write should take every reasonable step to be secure. You just never know. Even if only one person uses it, I'd deem this a more-than-reasonable step to take. I'm sure you could control the format via `DateTime.ToString(string)` to make it something SQL would understand, but there's really no reason to bother when the best solution is this easy.

Comment: OK, finally got through doing that (like I said, that was just a snippet; I actually had around 50 lines to edit and add parameters for!), but I am still getting an error. Will amend OP with it

Comment: Worth noting that if the input is from a DateTimePicker then you should just use the `.Value` property when calling `AddWithValue` which will avoid the `Convert.ToDateTime`

Comment: @MattWilko Done that now and it worked this time. Thanks

Comment: @MatthewHaugen have marked as answer, although as mentioned above I went back to using `Me.dateMain.Value` instead of converting, which seemed to work this time. Thanks

Comment: @MattWilko good point, I didn't notice that it was a `DateTimePicker`. Thanks, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ISO 8601 format (`YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]` or `YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss[.mmm]`) or use the unseparated format(`YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss[.mmm]`). Both should work fine.

Parameterized query is still better though.